# Calling method but nothing comes up

Tags: java

I'm writing a code for a bookstore, but I have two errors in the code that I can't seem to figure out. I've trying implementing a input method, scanner method, and I've tried various ways of trying to call the method but still can't figure it out. 
The code is as follows:

```
Planet[] anotherP= new Planet[5];
for (int i=0; i<anotherP.length; i++) anotherP[i]=new Planet();
// output the mass

for(int i = 0; i<anotherP.length; i++)
System.out.println("Mass:"+anotherP[i].getMass());

// sort
sort(anotherP);
System.out.println("Sorted:");

// sorted
for(int i = 0; i<anotherP.length; i++)
    System.out.println("Mass:" +anotherP[i].getMass());
```

Comment: You need to narrow the code you show down. This code has a few problems, so this is quite broad right now.

Comment: Your inner class `Store` does not contain a method called `Book()`...now, there is an `addBook()` method in the `Store` class that might work for you

Comment: @Carcigenicate I noted the specific problem below the code...I just didn't know if the entire code would help in solving the issue.

Comment: Please don't delete the code. It seems that it helped solving the question (see accepted answer) and without it nobody can understand what the answer is talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
myStore.Book(title, series, price, amount);
```

should be

```
Book book = new Book(title, series, price, amount);
```

to create an instance of `Book`.

Additionally you have to make your `Book` class a static inner class to be able to create an instance of it from a static context.

```
static class Books { ...
```

And the final thing: your class `Books` should be a class `Book`! It therefore should be

```
static class Book { ...
```

Comment: This fixed the error on the myStore.addBook(book); but now I have an error on Book book = new Book(title, series, price, amount); saying book cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: @Elijah check again!?

Comment: I tried that as well as well as changing store to static but I still am receiving the error that "book cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: @Elijah you have to write the class in upper case, `Book` is something different than `book`.

Comment: Apologies, I meant to capitalize that. It is saying "Book cannot be resolved to a type." Sorry.

Comment: @Elijah ah, damn it. Your code states `class Books` instead of `class Book`, not the trailing s?

Comment: I have a static class Books{ as well as a public void Books{

Comment: Thank you so much! Such a simple fix for something that gave me so many issues.